# How to apply edge detection filters on colored images on Sobel?

Tags: image-processing, sobel

I know how to do an image filter like the sobel-filter on 1 byte per pixel. However if you want to do it on RGB image with 24 bit per pixel, I don't know how to do it.

What is the best way to do that without having to convert the RGB image to a 8 bit one (greyscale)?

Comment: It is needed to add some codes here. We cannot understand your question exactly.

Comment: This question is liable to downvotes. Can you please provide a minimal example?

Comment: If you are using OpenCV, use `b,g,r = cv2.split(img)`, `Sobel(b...)`, `Sobel(g...), `Sobel(r...)`, `cv2.merge((b,g,r))`

Comment: Upvoted as this question is **clear enough**. You don’t always talk in code to tell the how, do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Sobel operator, like all other *linear* filter, one can apply the filter to each of the channels independently. That is, the output red channel is the filtered input red channel, etc.

Note that this is true only for *linear* filter. For any *nonlinear* filter, such a process leads to false colors.

Answer (score 0):

1. For each color channel, calculate gradient magnitudes (derivatives) by applying the Sobel operator and dividing by 8.
2. Unless you’re doing this for colorblinds, gradients (and edges from them) in every color channel do count. You could merge those gradient magnitude matrices into one matrix, keeping the highest magnitudes.